# Kendo Grid inline edit with Datetime DatePickerFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datetimepicker

kendo inline cell edit not support for datetime format. I need "dd/MMM/yyyy" data format but kendo grid shows "the filed date must be a date" error. can you please advice me to what to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you post questions that deal with HTML and JavaScript, it is always very helpful to others if you can also post an example of the code that you have tried so far. You can use jsFiddle or jsBin or StackOverflow's own code snippets: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom editor to do this.

References:

- [Grid Custom Editing](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom)
- [DatePicker.format](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-format)
- [Date Formatting](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting)

The code would look something like this (not tested, but it should be close enough to give you the right idea):

```
var customDateEditor = function (container, options) {
    $('<input />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDatePicker({
            format: "dd/MMM/yyyy"
        });
};

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    columns:[
        {
            field: "myDate",
            format: "dd/MMM/yyyy",
            editor: customDateEditor
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that editor templates need to be in `~Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder